# Laravel Database Schema, Nullable Foreign

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I've these two database tables:

1. User Tables
2. Partner Tables

**User Tables** will handle this kind of informations

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id')->unique();
      $table->string('email')->unique();
      $table->string('username')->unique();
      $table->string('password', 60);
      $table->string('photo')->nullable();
      $table->integer('partner_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('partner_id')->references('id')->on('partners');
      $table->rememberToken();
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

While **Partner Tables** will contains all the user meta information such as first name and last name, etc.

```
Schema::create('partners', function (Blueprint $table) {

    /**
     * Identity Columns
     */
    $table->increments('id')->unique();
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
    $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
    $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
    $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
    $table->string('website')->nullable();
    $table->string('phone')->nullable();
    $table->string('mobile')->nullable();
    $table->string('fax')->nullable();
    $table->date('birthdate')->nullable();
    $table->longText('bio')->nullable();
    $table->string('lang')->nullable(); //Language

    /**
     * Address Columns
     */
    $table->text('street')->nullable();
    $table->text('street2')->nullable();
    $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned(); // foreign
    $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
    $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();   // foreign
    $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('country_states');
    $table->string('city')->nullable();
    $table->string('district')->nullable();
    $table->string('area')->nullable();
    $table->string('zip')->nullable();
});
```

When a user is register to the site I only want few fields which are, `username`, `email address`, `password`, `first name` and `last name`. These are only the required fields.

So information in partner tables can be filled later after the user have finish registering to the site.

But due to the structure of foreign key, I cannot proceed any further because of this error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mytable`.`tbl_partners`, CONSTRAINT `partners_country_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_countries` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `tbl_partners` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `display_name`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Jack, Wilson, admin, admin@example.com, 2016-06-09 19:41:18, 2016-06-09 19:41:18))
```

I know this is cause by the countries table which is required by the partner table.
My question is : is there a work around so I can fill the country or any other non required data on partner table but keep the foreign table schema for countries, states, etc.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Set the `country_id` and the `state_id` nullable, like so.

```
$table->integer('country_id')->nullable()->unsigned();

$table->integer('state_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
```

Comment: If you need to change the field nullable after creating schema, then the line should be


$table->integer('country_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->change();

Comment: How do I defined the relationship for a ```nullable()->unsigned()``` field?   Also is this ```$table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries')``` needed?

Answer (score 128):

For laravel 7.x to create a nullable foreign key use simply:

```
$table->foreignId('country_id')->nullable()->constrained();

$table->foreignId('state_id')->nullable()->constrained();
```

REMEMBER: *nullable* should be **before** *constrained* otherwise the nullable will not be affected.

Comment: Peculiar behavior indeed. I'm interested as well why `nullable()` should come first.

Comment: I wasted one hour of working because I didn't know that nullable has to be written before constrained.

Comment: But why should `nullable()` comes first ?

Comment: It should come first, because that's how it is implemented. Also, if you think about it logically if you try and constrain and THEN say nullable, it's like trying to get in the way of the bullet, it's fired, THEN you put on the Kevlar vest.

Comment: it doesn't work for Laravel 9 `foreignIdFor()->nullable()`, it is NOT NULL, anyway. Any ideas how to make it null?

Comment: I might be going out on a limb here, but I believe that `foreignIdFor()` is just syntatic sugar. In other words, `foreignIdFor(some_id)` is basically equivalent to: `$table->bigInt('some_id')->unsigned()->references('some_id')->on('some_table')` (or something close to that) - because that's already strung together in this particular implementation, there's not a way to insert `nullable()` in the middle, where it apparently needs to be - you'd need to extend with your own function like `nullableForeignIdFor()` or something. This doesn't feel very laravel-y, but I hope that helps.

Answer (score 27):

With the latest version of Laravel, you can use the `nullable` method in conjunction of `foreignKey`:

```
$table
      ->foreignId('other_table_id')
      ->nullable() // here
      ->references('id')
      ->on('other_table');
```

Comment: How do I add if that foreign id on parent table is uuid?

Comment: @theodory something like:

`$table->foreignUuid('business_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('businesses')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');`

Answer (score 6):

For Laravel 7.x I use this way:

```
$table->bigInteger('word_type_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
$table->index('word_type_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('word_type_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('word_types')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? When I do this, I get a `Method 'nullable' not found in Illuminate\Database\Schema\ForeignKeyDefinition` warning.

Answer (score 6):

Note that if you have references('{column}')->on('{table}') you need to put the nullable()->constrained() before this ie:

```
$table->foreignId('author')->nullable()->constrained()->references('id')->on('users');
```

This is on Laravel 9 but probably earlier too.

Answer (score 3):

laravel 8

```
$table->foreignId('foreign_key_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Works fine in Laravel 9: `$table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\Catalogs\Projects\Type::class,'projecttype_id')->nullable()->comment('Project type')->index('projecttype_foreign')->constrained(\App\Models\Catalogs\Projects\Type::make()->getTable());`. Every modifier should be before the `constrained()` method. Otherwise, they'll be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('stock_indices')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why is that the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I've done with success in L10 this [fk nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) ex:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('partner_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('partner_id')->references('id')->on('partners');
```