# Laravel- Set default in foreign key

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I use  `SET DEFAULT` to constraint in foreign key as:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('phong', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine='InnoDB';
            $table->bigIncrements('p_id');
            $table->string('p_ma',50);
            $table->string('p_ten',50);
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('p_soNguoi')->default('0');
            $table->text('p_ghiChu',200)->nullable();
            $table->unique(['p_ma','p_ten']);
            $table->timestamp('p_taoMoi')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamp('p_capNhat')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('p_trangThai')->default('2');
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('lp_ma');
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('k_ma');
            $table->foreign('lp_ma')->references('lp_ma')->on('loaiphong')->onDelete('SET DEFAULT')->onUpdate('SET DEFAULT');
            $table->foreign('k_ma')->references('k_ma')->on('khu')->onDelete('SET DEFAULT')->onUpdate('SET DEFAULT');
        });
    }
```

But this is not working, this error is: Foreign key constraint is in
  correctly formed.
 When I want i delete a row from table 'khu' or 'loaiphong', this data of table won't delete. Any Idea? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Database Schema, Nullable Foreign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735055/laravel-database-schema-nullable-foreign)

Comment: I used "nullable()" for 'lp_ma' and 'k_ma' as your link. but it doesn't work :(. I dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

## Foreign Key Constraints

> Laravel also provides support for creating foreign key constraints, which are used to force referential integrity at the database level. For example, let's define a user_id column on the  posts table that references the id column on a users table:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

> You may also specify the desired action for the "on delete" and "on update" properties of the constraint:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
  ->references('id')->on('users')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

## Drop Column

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('phong', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('khu');
    });
}
```

[Read the full docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: I used "cascade" is ok. but it doesn't work with "set default" constraints

Comment: i got it. when i add drop column below your answear. thanks for your supporting :)