# Relationship 0...1 in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have 2 models: product and categories where each product belongs to one Categorie (**or none**)

Then I though put a "category_id" in product table. But category_id can be null.

In Laravel:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->default(0);
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

But when I need change a category to NULL (0) I obtain error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How Can I fixed?

Best regards

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735055/laravel-database-schema-nullable-foreign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `default` constraint.

You can't have a default value `0` since it is not present as an ID in your category table. Hence, child can't be present without a parent.

Rewrite

```
$table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->default(0);
```

to

```
$table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->nullable();
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that you always migrate parent table first before migrating the child table. In your case, migrate `categories` before `product` when you run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Thanks but problem is not fixed. Still error:                                 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.   Also I have field like fillable: protected $fillable = [ 'category_id' ];  I can asign to another integer value (another category_id) but I cannot asign value 0. Why??

Comment: In seeds I can asign default value 0. And I can change the value and asign the product for a category. But If I need switch this product and change category_id to 0 again I have this error...

Comment: A possible solution can be assign value 1 istead of 0 like disabled value and create a category (with category_id == 1) like a type of empty category. But may be have another better solution...

Comment: @JJMontalban You never said you ran seeds with this. If you are running seeds then you need to run Category seeds before Product seeds and not vice-versa. Also, did you create Product migration first before Category migration?

Comment: Order Migraton: 1. Categories 2. Products.  And order Seeds:  1. Categories 2. Products.   I havent any problem when I run "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
" And when I asign not null value in category_id. Must I change order on migration or seeds?

Comment: I have the order migration: products before categories and problem persists.

Comment: @JJMontalban Best possible case is not keep null values for category_id in products table.  Are you sure `products` run before `categories` when you run `php artisan migrate`? How about editing your post and showing us your migration and seed files? I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have fixed the problem assigning value 1 like empty category. Problem is null value. I can assign 0 in seeds but I cant return 0 value if I change default value. I dont know if Its a good solution but works...

Comment: But I dont know the funcionality of "->nullable()" in foregin key because I cannot asign NULL value...

Comment: @JJMontalban I am unable to perceive your exact issue. Are you getting this while running seeds or are you getting this while running migrations? Also, technically, when someone creates a product, it needs to assigned a proper category ID. There can't be any empty category as it makes no sense. Do you mind starting from scratch? I could guide you.

Comment: The fact is that I need to create a scheme that allows free products of any category. That is, when creating a product it should not correspond to any category. Also, repeat  I need to be able to free the product from an assigned category and the product does not belong to any category. I'm going to give you the answer as valid and create a new question for this. It could be clearer and serve more people.

Comment: Another question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702783/assign-null-value-to-foreign-key-in-laravel

Comment: @JJMontalban In that case, please delete your question since you meant something else.