# Create nullable foreign key laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, categories, database-migration

I am trying to add foreign key to my existing **Posts** table via migration. **Categories** table now empty and created before migration:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name', 255);
    $table->string('slug', 255);
    $table->json('text' )->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I have tried to create new column in **posts** table with constrained method:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

But getting error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sql_current`.`#sql-232_11eb`, CONSTRAINT `posts_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`))
```

Also, before I tried create nullable table:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories'); 
    });
}
```

But then I get another error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `sql_current`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`))
```

What am I doing wrong? I wan't to:

1. Create categories table.
2. Add nullable foreign column category_id to posts table.
3. Seed categories.
4. Attach categories to posts or leave it with null (where no data now).

Thank's for your suggestions!

Comment: Check output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE categories`. Does the column type match? This is usually a problem when working with columns created in an older version of Laravel which aren't always consistent with the newer version.

Comment: This means its the same: posts  CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned ... categories  CREATE TABLE `categories` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsi...

Comment: Create the category_id column on the table without the foreign key constraint, and nullable.  Then run a script to assign valid category_id to every record in the posts table.  Then add the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735055/laravel-database-schema-nullable-foreign